# Boolean value for linq query sets to false but is true in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm using a linq query in my method. When I step over my linq code my `isValid` variable sets to false. When it needs to be true. Why is `isValid` getting set to false how can I fix this?

**C# code**

```
    public void Method()
    {
        bool isValid = false;

        using(Database db = new Database())
        {
            isValid = (from x in db.TableName
                   where x.Column_A = "Data_Result" &&
                     x.Number_Col != 11
                   select x).Any();

            //Value of isValid = false???
        }

        ...
    }
```

**SQL Example**

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE Column_A = 'Data_Result' AND Number_Col <> 11
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure! , i mean this would be a pretty big bug. more likely you are pointing to the wrong database, or something else isnt as it seems

Comment: I looked at it a dozen of times :( I’m going to try it again

Comment: Debug, Have a look at your connection string in your datacontext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks good and I suspect, as TheGeneral, that the issue is that you're pointing to the wrong database.

You can verify this by getting the first few rows, top 10 maybe, and compare. Make sure you order by `Id` so you get the same results.

```
db.TableName
.OrderBy(r=>r.Id)
.Top(10);
```

You could add

`.Where( x => x.Column_A == "Data_Result")`

etc.

---

## Update

I just noticed that you have a single equal mark in your code `x.Column_A = "Data_Result"`. Is this your real code?